# How to create a border each of three flexboxes and Name, company logo and the company name as seen in the image?

Tags: html, css, frontend, xhtml

In a WordPress page, I am trying to display static columns of contents as seen in the image below. Tried to use flex the structure, but can't get it right it yet. Please suggest possible approaches. I know I got a lot closer to the solution than when I posted this questions a couple days ago. Adding a a border around each of these testimonials and aligning icon, name and company logo is the last part of this task.

[image]

I could only do as much as the image below shows with the HTML and the CSS that follow it. I would also need to ensure this section is mobile friendly.

[image]

```css
.testimonial-outer-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-content: normal;
}

.testimonial-heading {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display';
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #cea67e;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.testimonial-subheading {
  font-family: Roboto;
  text-align: centered;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.testimonial-block {
  background-color: #67213f;
  margin-bottom: 1.6rem;
}

.testimonial-container {
  border: solid 1px;
  border-color: #cea67e;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="testimonial-block">
  <div class="wrap-x">
    <div class="inside">
      <div class="col col-xs-12 center-xs">
        <div class="testimonial-heading">TESTIMONIALS</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-xs-12 center-xs">
        <div class="testimonial-subheading">Hear from our Delighted Clients</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-xs-12 col-md-4 testimonial-outer-box">
          <div class="testimonial-box">
            <div class="testimonial-container">
              <div class="testimonial-title">THANK YOU! The PwP gifts we recently sent out have been a huge hit with our clients and internal team.</div>
              <div class="testimonial-picture">
                <picture>
                  <source media="(max-width: 360px)" srcset="https://dev-packed-with-purpose.pantheonsite.io/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/Bailiwick.png">
                  <source media="(max-width: 668px)" srcset="https://dev-packed-with-purpose.pantheonsite.io/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/Bailiwick.png">
                  <source media="(max-width: 1024px)" srcset="https://dev-packed-with-purpose.pantheonsite.io/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/Bailiwick.png">
                  <source srcset="https://dev-packed-with-purpose.pantheonsite.io/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/Bailiwick.png">
                  <img src="https://dev-packed-with-purpose.pantheonsite.io/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/Bailiwick.png" alt="">
                </picture>
              </div>
              <div class="testimonial-author">-Amanda K.</div>
              <div class="testimonial-job">Bailiwick</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-xs-12 col-md-4 testimonial-outer-box">
          <div class="testimonial-box">
            <div class="testimonial-container">
              <div class="testimonial-title">I love the package options, but most importantly I love the amazing purpose behind each box. Such a great meaning and inspiration. Whether I need a gift for a friend, family member, or a business partner, you all have a package to meet all their needs.</div>
              <div class="testimonial-picture">
                <picture>
                  <source media="(max-width: 360px)" srcset="https://dev-packed-with-purpose.pantheonsite.io/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/Veracity.png">
                  <source media="(max-width: 668px)" srcset="https://dev-packed-with-purpose.pantheonsite.io/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/Veracity.png">
                  <source media="(max-width: 1024px)" srcset="https://dev-packed-with-purpose.pantheonsite.io/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/Veracity.png">
                  <source srcset="https://dev-packed-with-purpose.pantheonsite.io/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/Veracity.png">
                  <img src="https://dev-packed-with-purpose.pantheonsite.io/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/Veracity.png" alt="">
                </picture>
              </div>
              <div class="testimonial-author">-Sarah C.,</div>
              <div class="testimonial-job">Veracity Networks</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-xs-12 col-md-4 testimonial-outer-box">
          <div class="testimonial-box">
            <div class="testimonial-container">
              <div class="testimonial-title">Our employees have been singing your praises and sharing on their LinkedIn feeds not only your amazing products but your professionalism and outstanding customer support.</div>
              <div class="testimonial-picture">
                <picture>
                  <source media="(max-width: 360px)" srcset="https://dev-packed-with-purpose.pantheonsite.io/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/LearnOnDemand.png">
                  <source media="(max-width: 668px)" srcset="https://dev-packed-with-purpose.pantheonsite.io/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/LearnOnDemand.png">
                  <source media="(max-width: 1024px)" srcset="https://dev-packed-with-purpose.pantheonsite.io/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/LearnOnDemand.png">
                  <source srcset="https://dev-packed-with-purpose.pantheonsite.io/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/LearnOnDemand.png">
                  <img src="https://dev-packed-with-purpose.pantheonsite.io/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/LearnOnDemand.png" alt="">
                </picture>
              </div>
              <div class="testimonial-author">-Melanie H., </div>
              <div class="testimonial-job">Learn on Demand Systems</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i'll suggest to take a look to flexbox

Comment: Thanks, I tried to have a look at it in a video tutorial, but couldn't understand it well. Can you show me an example of how to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a code I used In similar to your website

`row is the container where you should put your pictures and apply this code in css. kindly change it to appropriate class`

```
.row{
    display:flex;
    flex-dirction:row;
    justify-content:space-evenly;
    wrap:flex-wrap;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but the wrap:flex-wrap; says invalid property. Please recheck it.

Comment: Hi Sethu, this is the page that I'm working on. Please find the section at its bottom that I need your help with. https://dev-packed-with-purpose.pantheonsite.io/corporate-gifts-new/

Comment: I'm happy to help. Kindly give more details and accept the answer